# School assignment onChange

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem that hopefully someone can help with. I am a student in a Web Programming Class, the instructor has given the assignment to: Add an "onChange" event handler to the shipping field in the form to run the "shipping_price()" function whenever the user changes the selected shipping method.

Here is the code he offered:

```
<td colspan="3" align="right"><span class="fmlabel">Shipping:</span>
  <select name="shipping">
     <option value="0">Select a Shipping Method
     <option value="7.95">3-5 days ($7.95)
     <option value="9.95">2 days ($9.95)
     <option value="12.95">Next Day ($12.95)
  </select>
</td>
```

What I put here is all the information he gave for this part of the assignment, any help would be great.

Edit:

I took the suggested help and put this in:

```
 function shipping_price()
    {
    var ship=document.getElementById("shipping");
    document.order.total.value=(shipping+sub_total);
}

 <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right"><span class="fmlabel">Shipping:</span>
       <select name="shipping" onChange="shipping_price">
          <option value="0">Select a Shipping Method
          <option value="7.95">3-5 days ($7.95)
          <option value="9.95">2 days ($9.95)
          <option value="12.95">Next Day ($12.95)
       </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="numbers" name="sub8" id="sub8" size="7" value="0.00" disabled></td>
 </tr>
```

This works if I change the value of the shipping field, but will not put the "option value=" into the shipping field.

Comment: If you expect us to solve your assignment completely for you, then that sort of beats the whole purpose of learning ! It would be best if you try something out and then share with us and we would help you along the way

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Was not looking for the solution, looking for a little assistance, as I was unable to find any information regarding this issue. This is a project that we have never done before and as you can see he is not giving any information for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this .There are many site for reading deeply.The below is one of the method.When the value in the select is changed to the new value. Then the functionfirst() will call and the functionfirst() will the alert the selected value.

```
 <script>
    function functionfirst(){
      var myselect = document.getElementById("shipping");
      alert(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);
    }
    </script>

    <td colspan="3" align="right"><span class="fmlabel">Shipping:</span>
  <select id="shipping" name="shipping" onchange="functionfirst()">
     <option value="0">Select a Shipping Method</option>
     <option value="7.95">3-5 days ($7.95)</option>
     <option value="9.95">2 days ($9.95)</option>
     <option value="12.95">Next Day ($12.95)</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: This has given me a direction to go, I have gotten it to start working, but how do I get it to change the shipping value in the field:

    <td><input class="numbers" name="sub8" id="sub8" size="7" value="0.00" disabled></td>

the way it is the field is left with the value of "0.00" and will not add to the total box of the order

Comment: You could add the following line in the script.document.getElementById("sub8").value=(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);